# How to deal with extremly big numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

I am making a idle game like http://www.clickerheroes.com/ . I am doing it using createjs html library(doesnt matter). Anyways what i want to know is how i can deal with extremly large numbers that will occur in such games (10x10^100) because javascript doesnt support such big numbers or am i wrong here?

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: This seems a general programming problem not specific to game development. There's already [a question on StackOverflow about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/is-there-a-bignum-library-for-javascript).

Comment: @Anko I agree with your comment but handling big numbers for game purposes *might* be different from doing so for other purposes. For instance you might fake or very roughly approximate the value because it is only for representational value and the exactness is not important. I suggested the same solution that I would for more precise purposes because it is simple enough to implement.

Comment: I'm curious to know what the large numbers represent; couldn't this be represented in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a library that handles those numbers:
https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js